# Problems with Session.save()

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate and as I researched, I have found out that the HQL insert query gets data from other tables. According to what I've read, I can make use of session.save for the insert functionality. 
In my DAO I have this addToCart() method

```
@Override
public void addToCart(ShoppingCart cart) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(cart);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();

}
```

The code above doesn't work. Maybe I am missing something because I'm still new to hibernate.

Comment: Change `openSession` to `getCurrentSession`. There's no point constantly creating and destroying a session for each transaction.

Comment: are you getting any exception?